# ClickOnce + Restart = Opens Browser?

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, updates

I'm deploying a ClickOnce Application and want to restart the application after it was updated. Therefore I wrote following code:

```
  private async void updateCheck()
    {
        using (var releaser = await _asyncLock.LockAsync())
        {
            UpdateCheckInfo info = null;
            bool updateAvailable = false;

            if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
            {
                ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
                ad.UpdateCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Ad_UpdateCompleted);

                try
                {
                    updateAvailable = ad.CheckForUpdate(false);
                    info = ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate();

                }
                catch (DeploymentDownloadException dde)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The new version of the application cannot be downloaded at this time. \n\nPlease check your network connection, or try again later. Error: " + dde.Message);
                    return;
                }
                catch (InvalidDeploymentException ide)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot check for a new version of the application. The ClickOnce deployment is corrupt. Please redeploy the application and try again. Error: " + ide.Message);
                    return;
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This application cannot be updated. It is likely not a ClickOnce application. Error: " + ioe.Message);
                    return;
                }

                if (/*info.UpdateAvailable*/ updateAvailable)
                {
                    Boolean doUpdate = true;

                    if (!info.IsUpdateRequired)
                    {
                        MessageBoxResult dr = MessageBox.Show("An update is available. Would you like to update the application now?", "Update Available", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                        if (!(MessageBoxResult.OK == dr))
                        {
                            doUpdate = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Display a message that the app MUST reboot. Display the minimum required version.
                        MessageBox.Show("This application has detected a mandatory update from your current " +
                            "version to version " + info.MinimumRequiredVersion.ToString() +
                            ". The application will now install the update and restart.",
                            "Update Available", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                            MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    }

                    if (doUpdate)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //ad.Update();

                            ad.UpdateAsync();                                                               
                        }
                        catch (DeploymentDownloadException dde)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the latest version of the application. \n\nPlease check your network connection, or try again later. Error: " + dde);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Ad_UpdateCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The application has been upgraded, and will now restart.");
            String ApplicationEntryPoint = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdatedApplicationFullName;

            Process.Start(ApplicationEntryPoint);

            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunate in UpdatedApplicationFullName a URL to the Website where the deployment packages are stored. So Process.Start(ApplicationEntryPoint) opens a Browser Window and tries to download the package once again.

The behaviour I want is that the Process.Start(...) opens the new updated application.

Has anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing `Process.Start(ApplicationEntryPoint);` to  `Process.Start(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);` ?

Comment: Hi, I've tried this and it restarts some instance of that application executable file but it seems to be not correct. I've added a statusbar field which should display following value ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString(); In the restarted value nothing is shown there. I think it might be because it starts the exe directly and not the .application file.